# Why do we only build 7th chords on the supertonic and dominant of a major scale?

Tags: chords, chord-theory, harmony

I am just cracking into a book on basic Harmony (Mark Sarnecki, 2nd edition), and the first section begins with a review of the triads built on each degree of a C major scale, as shown in this picture.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Then after introducing the various types of 7th chords, the same sequence of chords is considered, along 7th chords built on the supertonic and dominant of the C major scale, as shown below.

[image: Screenshot 2]

It results in a minor 7th chord built on D, and a dominant seventh chord build on G.

**My actual question**:

It seems rather arbitrary that we've only done this on the second and fifth degree of the scale.  Why not build a minor 7th chord upon E as well? or a major 7th chord on F? or all of the notes in the scale for that matter?

Comment: *We* do. As for why *he* didn't, I have no idea. That's to say that you can build triads or 7th chords or 9th chords or whatever from any degree of any scale by stacking 3rds.

Comment: Yeah I don’t know about anyone else but I build seventh chords on other scale degrees all the time.

Comment: If I'm allowed to be _really_ cynical, then here is my immediate thought: Some people think that music theory is a way to decide whether something sounds good or bad, and a recipe for how music ought to be written. In reality, it's just a glossary and language developed so that we can _discuss_ things like what sounds good or bad, or what characterises different music styles, in a constructive manner. By omitting things, it seems like this book tries to say that such things don't exist, or just that "that's not something we do", going directly against the purpose of music theory.

Comment: Yes, in short:  You can do whatever you want, but some things are uncommon in conventional use.  I see this attitude of "what are we allowed to do" as well as accepting conventions of use and nomenclature as though they were facts of Nature all over the place on StackExchange, and suspect that they're rampant in music in general.  You don't even have to stick to Equal Temperament, a tuning which I'm sure some or even many musicians have lived their entire lives believing provided the sole primary colors of harmony.

Comment: I suspect this is focused on "very" classical music, where these two chords the main chords that a seventh are added to (I don't know why this is. The idea of the seventh was still a relatively new concept)

Comment: This is somewhat misleading here - We don't only build diatonic 7th chords on the scale degrees 2 and 5.  We also build them on other degrees, too.  Further, we also have a set of diatonic **9ths, 11ths, and even 13ths...** etc.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We do! It's just that that book doesn't...yet.

We build seventh chords on all scale degrees; the seventh chord on scale-degree 3 in major, for instance, is a minor seventh.

But beginning musicians, especially those in the popular genres, get the most bang for their buck with seventh chords on scale-degrees 2 and 5 so that they can create that nice circle-of-fifths ii7-V7-I progression.

This book is almost certainly only presenting those two seventh chords for easy clarity early on.

This text is the "basic" *Harmony* by Sarnecki. The book comes in three volumes (Basic, Intermediate, Advanced), and based on the Amazon description for the [Intermediate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1554402719) volume, the seventh chords you mention are found there:

> The Intermediate level addresses fundamentals of harmonization; harmonic sequences; **leading-note and other diatonic 7th chords**; tonicization and secondary dominants; modulation; dominant 9th, 11th, and 13th chords; the Bach Chorales; form and analysis; and melody writing.

Comment: "We do" ... Jinx!

Comment: @user37496 <user is unable to comment on account of the jinx>

Comment: "Or maybe it just doesn't yet" Quite likely. If there's one thing a beginner book shouldn't do, is smash down the entirety of music theory all at once. I suspect the author simply used this subset because it fit his approach best.

Comment: We certainly do! To the extent that most of us seem to use ii7 > V7 > Imaj7 more than just I for resolution. Maybe, later in the book, it gets into all that - it jolly well should ! Perhaps with a footnote on the page shown, to whet the reader's appetite?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  If I am understanding correctly, I could just as well have added a seventh on to every triad; but the author simply chooses to emphasize those two first.

Comment: @KyleSchlitt Exactly right! Later studies will show that, not only can you put sevenths on anything, you can use different types of sevenths. Keep at it!

Comment: "user is unable to comment on account of the jinx" xD nice joke!

Answer (score 4):

In jazz and modern classical music, all kinds of 7th chords and beyond are used. But in the past, the most common 7th chords in classical music were built on the supertonic and dominant scale degrees for a very simple reason.

The ii chord and IV chords function as subdominants Mash them together and you get a iim7.
The V chord and the diminished vii function as dominants.  Mash them together and you get a V7 chord.

These 7th chords developed because of the shared function, but also because the m7 created a dissonance that was not so striking and out of place in the music.

Answer (score 2):

> Why not build a minor 7th chord upon E as well? or a major 7th chord
>   on F? or all of the notes in the scale for that matter?

You are reading way too much into things: **Nowhere** in the content you posted does it say that 7th chords are only built on those two scale degrees. It's simply an opening exercise introducing 7th chords in two of their most important, common usages in western music.

As others have mentioned, we can and do build 7th chords on any note of any scale, and certainly the book deals with other types of 7th chords further on.

Comment: When absorbing material for the first time, many things are not obvious at all to a beginner even though they are crystal clear to an expert such as yourself.  Thank you for your addition.

Comment: @KyleSchlitt - Thanks, but I'm not an expert - I just know a few things. There are experts on here, but they don't include me.

Comment: This is what the user actually needs: an explanation they they have misread their textbook.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the picture, we have major and minor triads, and to each we can add a

major or minor 7th: MM7(M7),     Mm7(7), mm7(m7),     mM7 (rarely used).

```
         key C: CM7 FM7 GM7, G7,     Dm7 Em7 Am7, DmM7 EmM7 AmM7
```